# What CSS buttons work really well in Web Views (iPhone/android)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, android, css

And it will look like a real button. When you press on the button, it has an "umph" effect.

What CSS button is smooth when done inside a web view. Hopefully, so smooth that it looks and feels like a native button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Native" buttons look different on every device. So, you can style a button in a multitude of ways, and if you don't like the effects that CSS offers (and at this point, there are many of them), you can roll your own with images that roll over (and/or animate).  But it still won't look native unless you go crazy and detect devices and deliver buttons tailored to look like native buttons.

Are you asking what sort of CSS options you have for displaying buttons?

Comment: I want a CSS button that "feels" like a native button when you push on it. And doesn't have any "lag"

Comment: The lag will largely depend on the power of the device.  Using the iphone as an example, you won't notice much in the way of lag (if any) with a CSS or javascript img/rollover button. Older blackberries? Who knows. At the end of the day you're giving up this sort of control for the benefit of just writing it once as a web app rather than coding 10 different flavors for every mobile OS out there.